# .htaccess for apache userdir's

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

basically i have a web server set up where all sites are in /var/www but i want to be able to do development in ~/public_html/sitename so i set userdir's up in apache but the links still goto the /var/www directories pages.

I know i could go in and change all the links, but i think an htaccess would be easier.

So my question is, is it possible to say:

We have a folder in my public_html on home which is accessed via example.com/~jackyyll/project

I want all requests from that project to be redirected to ~/jackyyll/project/request_here

I've tried some things in the .htaccess but nothing is working.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should really be looking into getting [mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_userdir.html) working as opposed to using mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `mod_userdir`, a simple `AliasMatch` can do the trick. Here is what I use to map `www.kylheku.com/~kaz/` to `/home/kaz/public-www/`, et cetera, straight from my `httpd.conf`:

```
# /~user/blah goes to /home/user/public-www/blah
AliasMatch ^/~([a-z]+)/(.*) /home/$1/public-www/$2

# /~user and goes to /home/user/public-www/
AliasMatch ^/~([a-z]+)$ /home/$1/public-www/
```

`AliasMatch` has some capabilities resembling `mod_rewrite`, except, just like `Alias` what it does is it takes URL's coming into the server and maps them to paths. The output is not re-injected into the request processing chain.  Any URL mapped by `Alias` or `AliasMatch` bypasses the `VirtualHost`-s and their docroots. It's like a special exception mechanism.

The `.htaccess` in the user's `public-www` directory works just fine. I have `RewriteRules` there and other cruft.

Of course, this is a lot simpler than `mod_userdir`. It maps all possible usernames to all possible userdir directories, whether or not they exist. `mod_userdir` has more bells and whistles, like restricting which users have a userdir, and alternative userdirs certain users.

Comment: similar need : https://stackoverflow.com/a/76440726/6614155