# .htaccess Deny acces to the image folder, but allow acces to view single images

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Can I config a .htaccess that deny the direcly acces to "/images" but "/images/*.jpg" must be allowed because I show single pictures on my index.php from this folder!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable directory browsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that. OP requires a single folder being blocked except the extension .jpg. That question is to block directory browsing and all sub-directories entirely.

Comment: The question is worded differently, but it is a duplicate, because this is exactly what is asked. `Options -Indexes` in an htaccess file *inside subdirectory images* disallows access to to the directory listing, but allows access to its content.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^/images/?$
```

This will deny access to the `/images/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

This would block access to a specific folder, but ***should*** still allow images to be displayed:

```
<Files /images>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

You can also include (if the above **alone** does not work):

```
<Files .jpg>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

This ***should*** allow access to all images with file extension .jpg after you have denied access to the /images folder.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was interested to the same thing. However not one of the methods proposed, are working.
In the same folder, I got MP3 and JPG files. If I use the above methodes,, I get access to both.

The solution proposed here, works very well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396033/blocking-pdf-files-from-direct-access-using-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Amit Verma, to complete :
in my case in UserDir, I should specify path from "root" folder :

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^/~userDirName/subFolder/folderThatRequiredProtection/?$
```

*.htaccess* file is in *folderThatRequiredProtection*

You can also protect a file :

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/~userDirName/subFolder/folderThatRequiredProtection/fileThatRequiredProtection?$
```

You can put also 403 for file (and 404 for folder), but sometimes, it should be better to put 404 and hacker doesn't know it exists !